# Install Pandas for Jupyter notebook in Binder

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter notebook in GitHub and wanted to run it in Binder so other people can play with it.

However it complains that pandas is not installed.
The error is:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

How can I get Binder to install pandas for this instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to edit/create `requirements.txt` at the base of the repo. I have tried to use the pip install method in a cell and this did not work for Binder as it prevents live installations in your session.

You can list the modules you need and specify versions if you need to.

There is an example in this GitHub:

- https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements/blob/master/requirements.txt

Contents are:

```
numpy==1.16.*
matplotlib==3.*
seaborn==0.8.1
pandas
```

Comment: Had the same problem with Plotly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The note about MyBinder preventing live installations may have been true; however, it isn't entirely true now. For Pandas (& many packages) you can run `%pip install pandas` in a cell in the session & it will get installed into the environment **in that session**. A few complex packages have install processes not compatible with that & so they won't fully function & need to be present initially. That being said, I emphasize the install done in the session doesn't persist. You'll want to update your configuration files, such as `requirements.txt`, so the next session has the package at startup.

Comment: Related to that if you are using `environment.yml` for your configuration, you can use the appropriate variation of `%conda install` inside the session and it will typically work. The specific command is important so use the anaconda site as a resource for the command. For example, searching 'anaconda pandas' brings you to [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas) that shows the full command in this case is `%conda install -c anaconda pandas`. Magic installs commands: [see here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 0):

It is noteworthy to mention that the `requirements.txt` file has to be created in the GitHub repository, not in the Binder UI. The Binder UI is also read only and will not sync any file back to GitHub. Any `requirements.txt` in the Binder UI will not be picked up and also if reloading the runtime or refreshing the page it will not be considered. When the `requirements.txt` is created, launch again [Binder UI start page](https://mybinder.org) pointing to the GitHub repository.